# How to extend Ruby Test::Unit assertions to include assert_false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, assertions

Apparently there is no `assert_false` in Test::Unit. How would you add it by extending assertions and adding the file `config/initializers/assertions_helper.rb`?

Is this the best way to do it? I don't want to modify `test/unit/assertions.rb`.

By the way, I don't think it is redundant. I was using `assert_equal false, something_to_evaluate`. The problem with this approach is that it is easy to accidentally use `assert false, something_to_evaluate`. This will always fail, doesn't throw an error or warning, and invites bugs into the tests.

Comment: http://www.natontesting.com/2009/07/21/add-assert_false-to-rubys-testunit/, the work link is a hyperlink but see the same above.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using MiniTest (replaced Test::Unit in Ruby 1.9+), then you can use the `refute` method, which is the inverse of `assert`.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I find the name `assert_false` better than `refute` because it's consistent with all the other assertions, and it's also usually more aligned with the semantics (similar to using `if !condition` instead of `unless`).

If you feel the same way and want `assert_false`, add it in `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  ...

  def assert_false(test, message="Expected: false. Actual: #{test}.")
    assert_equal false, test, message
  end

end
```

EDIT: Note that `assert !test` (suggested elsewhere) wouldn't work if `test` is nil (!nil is true, and we probably want `assert_false(nil)` to fail). So this is a direct comparison to `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Rails 4 has `assert_not` which does what you want.

```
test "requires valid url" do
  @mymodel.url = "bogus!"
  assert_not @mymodel.valid?
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a bang in front of what you are asserting:

```
assert !(something_false)
```